# What are the API that does implement JSR-353 (JSON)

Tags: java, json, jackson, interface-implementation, jsr-353

I just found out that Jackson does not implement JSR-353 and we already designed the module.. so i am in a desperate hurry to find a replacement of this API to begin working ! :D

I searched an API that implements the standard but could not find any interesting result because we plan to code with the standard and force the system to use a particular implementation (the API i am desperately searching for)

Comment: I know that Jackson, Gson, etc.. does exist and are the better ones but the implementation thing is problematic so my question does simply mean "do you know about an api that implements the standard json jsr-353" so i thnik that it's not a recommandation or something like that no ?

Comment: some users on Stack Overflow are becoming "purists". This was a really interesting question as it is for me also hard to find a list of the apis that implement JSR353. When the rules start working against the users' interests, you have to start thinking about changing some...

Comment: Note that [JSR-374](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=374), as an update to JSR-353, has been released and included in Java EE 8.

Comment: On the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, see: [*Actual implementation of JSR-353 (JSON)?*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47697/actual-implementation-of-jsr-353-json)

Answer (score 15):

## Reference implementation

Here is the reference implementation for [*JSR 353*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353) and its successor [*JSR 374: Java<sup>TM</sup> API for JSON Processing 1.1*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=374) in Java EE 8:

https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/

### Binding

Related is [*JSR 367: Java<sup>TM</sup> API for JSON Binding (JSON-B)*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=367) and its reference implementation, [*Eclipse Yasson*](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.yasson).

Comment: I think it is not a finalized project no ? clicking on "Documentation" directs me to a "Oracle : We're sorry, the page you requested was not found".

Comment: @maher.belkh The URL is wrong. I don't know if it changed or if they got it wrong, but the documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsonp.htm).

Comment: Here are the API docs: https://json-processing-spec.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/fcs/javadocs/index.html

Comment: They fixed the URL on site since then.

Answer (score 5):

## Genson

The `Genson` library claims to implement JSR-353.

https://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/JSR353

I haven't tried this one myself though. I was recently also looking for a good JSON library, I tried 3 of them and finally settled with using Jackson as it best served my needs. The different thing is that I wasn't looking for a library which precisely implements the standard, I was just looking for something which is simple and does what I wanted it to do.

---

You can check `Gson` too, I guess (though it's not directly related to JSR-353).

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: I was going to settle for Jackson but when i found out that it does not implement the standard that become impossible. And i cannot afford to use the application server to use its own implementation (if he has one which i doubt) so the need to have an API that does implement JSR-353 is mandatory unfortunately.

When you say Gson is not directly related to JSR-353 you mean there is a chance that it could be ?

Comment: @maher.belkh I mean, I don't see it in their docs that it's related. I am not sure.

Comment: I am Genson author, indeed it implements jsr 353 and just works

Comment: Both project has moved to GitHub. New Genson page is [here](https://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/Extensions/#jsr-353---java-api-for-json-processing) and Gson moved [here](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: @eugen What about Genson supporting [JSR 374](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=374), the successor to JSR 353? And does your binding feature implement [JSON-B](http://json-b.net) defined in JSR 367? I suggest adding to your [FAQ](http://genson.io/Faq/) to make this known.

Comment: @BasilBourque no it doesn't implement JSONB.